# Extract early attribute values without full Get-Content

Tags: xml, powershell

In PowerShell I know I can do something like this:

```
[xml]$myxml = Get-Contents .\oneofmyxmlfiles.xml
$myxml.Wrapper.Data.HeaderStuff.SomeHeaderAttribute
```

and get the result I want (`WhatIWantToExtract`) from something like

```
<Wrapper>
    <Data>
        <HeaderStuff SomeHeaderAttribute="WhatIWantToExtract" />
...a bunch of other stuff...
    </Data>
...a bunch of more other stuff...
</Wrapper>
```

I need to do this for **many** files which can be **quite large**. But, the HeaderStuff element is **unique** and always very **near the top** of the file.

Is there a way to extract "directly" from near the top the file, without loading the whole contents with Get-Content?

Comment: A simple solution is using the `TotalCount` parameter of `Get-Content`, but I'm not sure how to load XML fragments like that.  `Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 10`.  This has the aliases `Head` and `First`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use TheIncorrigible1 suggestion, "use TotalCount parameter of Get-Content":

```
$fivelines = Get-Content .\oneofmyxmlfiles.xml -TotalCount 5
```

The result is a `System.Array` with five elements. My XML files have a very predictable structure, so I can easily isolate the specific line (array element) I need, then use simple string matching techniques to get out the attribute value I am after.

Thanks to Tomalak, your solution seems more elegant and robust, but more work than I am willing to do at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.NET XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader) to read into an XML file and stop processing it any further as soon as you have the info you need.

Advantage: It's extremely fast and uses next to no memory. Disadvantage: You have to use e.g. flags to maintain the context of what you're reading, because the reader works like moving a cursor through a file. It only maintains its position and what kind of thing it's currently looking at; you have to do all necessary book-keeping.

The following returns the value of the `SomeHeaderAttribute` attribute of the first `<HeaderStuff>` element it encounters and stops processing after that. Adapt to your specific XML layout and needs.

```
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.Xml

function Get-HeaderStuff {
    param([string]$xmlFilePath)

    try {
        $stream = New-Object FileStream -ArgumentList ($xmlFilePath, [FileMode]::Open)

        $settings = New-Object XmlReaderSettings
        $settings.Async = $false

        $reader = [XmlReader]::Create($stream, $settings)
        while ($reader.Read()) {
            if (
                $reader.NodeType -eq [XmlNodeType]::Element -and 
                $reader.Name -eq "HeaderStuff"
            ) {
                return $reader.GetAttribute("SomeHeaderAttribute")
            }
        }
    } finally {
        # clean up
        if ($reader) { $reader.Dispose() }
        if ($stream) { $stream.Dispose() }
    }
}
```

You would call it with a path to your XML file:

```
$result = Get-HeaderStuff ".\oneofmyxmlfiles.xml"
Write-Host $result
```