# Class based streamReader & xmlReader locks files, function doesn't

Tags: powershell, oop, streamreader, xmlreader

I am refactoring some function based XML reader code to class methods, and seeing some issues. With the function, I can run a test and verify the XML loaded right, then change the XML and test for error conditions. But this class based approach fails due to "the file is open in another program", forcing me to close the console before I can revise the XML.
Initially I was using the path directly in the xmlReader. So I moved to a StreamReader input to the xmlReader. And I even played with creating an all new xmlDocument and importing the root node of the loaded XML into that new xmlDocument. None works. 
I suspect the reason the function based version works is because the xmlReader variable is local scope, so it goes out of scope when the function completes. But I'm grasping at straws there. I also read that Garbage Collection could be an issue, so I added `[system.gc]::Collect()` right after the Dispose and still no change.

```
class ImportXML {
    # Properties
    [int]$status = 0
    [xml.xmlDocument]$xml = ([xml.xmlDocument]::New())
    [collections.arrayList]$message = ([collections.arrayList]::New())

    # Methods
    [xml.xmlDocument] ImportFile([string]$path) {
        $importError = $false
        $importFile = ([xml.xmlDocument]::New())
        $xmlReaderSettings = [xml.xmlReaderSettings]::New()
        $xmlReaderSettings.ignoreComments = $true
        $xmlReaderSettings.closeInput = $true
        $xmlReaderSettings.prohibitDtd = $false
        try {
            $streamReader = [io.streamReader]::New($path)
            $xmlreader = [xml.xmlreader]::Create($streamReader, $xmlReaderSettings)
            [void]$importFile.Load($xmlreader)
            $xmlreader.Dispose
            $streamReader.Dispose
        } catch {
            $exceptionName = $_.exception.GetType().name
            $exceptionMessage = $_.exception.message
            switch ($exceptionName) {
                Default {
                    [void]$this.message.Add("E_$($exceptionName): $exceptionMessage")
                    $importError = $true
                }
            }
        }

        if ($importError) {
            $importFile = $null
        }

        return $importFile
    }
}

class SettingsXML : ImportXML {
    # Constructor
    SettingsXML([string]$path){
        if ($this.xml = $this.ImportFile($path)) {
            Write-Host "$path!"
        } else {
            Write-Host "$($this.message)"
        }
    }
}

$settingsPath = '\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools\Dev 4.0\Settings.xml'
$settings = [SettingsXML]::New($settingsPath)
```

EDIT:
 I also tried a FileStream rather than a StreamReader, with FileShare of ReadWrite, like so

```
$fileMode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
$fileAccess = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read
$fileShare = [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite
$fileStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream $path, $fileMode, $fileAccess, $fileShare
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right lines with `Dispose`, but you're not actually *invoking* the method - you're just getting a reference to it and then not doing anything with it...

Compare:

```bsh
PS> $streamReader = [io.streamReader]::New(".\test.xml");
PS> $streamReader.Dispose

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Dispose()
void IDisposable.Dispose()
PS> _
```

with

```bsh
PS> $streamReader = [io.streamReader]::New(".\test.xml");
PS> $streamReader.Dispose()
PS> _
```

You need to add some `()` after the method name so your code becomes:

```bsh
$xmlreader.Dispose()
$streamReader.Dispose()
```

And then it should release the file lock ok.

Comment: Also the dispose call should be in a `finally` block, not in the `try` block.

Comment: @Tomalak - and you'd need to check the objects are not null in the catch before you dispose them in case the error happened before they both got instantiated (e.g. $path doesn't exist) :-)

Comment: Aha! And.... dang it! I really am just slow in groking this move to classes. Because as soon as you said that, I remembered a completely unrelated issue where I was referencing the method as an object rather than calling the method, and getting something back that wasn't what I expected. Gah. Hopefully I don't need a third time before it's a charm. ;)

Comment: @mclayton Absolutely: `try { ... } catch { ... } finally { if ($xmlreader) { $xmlreader.Dispose() } }`.

Comment: This does beg the question, if one wanted to work with an XML file, using a streamReader because the file is huge, and manage the sharing of that file while working with it, one would need to start with a fileStream to manage access, and feed that info a streamReader to handle the file size, and feed that into an xmlReader to get the XML functionality, correct? Or is a fileStream already going to handle the file size? In which case, when would one ever just use a streamReader over a fileStream? Or is it the other pair, & an xmlReader is also a streamReader, so I can send the fileStream direct?

Comment: @Tomalak, curious about your Try Catch Finally. If I put the dispose there it shows as an error "Variable is not defined in the method". It has to be in the Try to work. AM I doing something wrong there as well?

Comment: @Tomalak, further clarification. If I have `$xmlreader = $null` before the Try, then `$xmlreader = [xml.xmlreader]::Create($fileStream, $xmlReaderSettings)` in the Try, it works. Is that suggesting that one should always initialize variables at the top of the method, before any use, even if it means initializing as $null?

Comment: A `FileStream` is specifically for interacting with files. A `StreamReader` is more generic and could also sit at the end of a network socket. So for reading XML files, a `FileStream` is sufficient. The `XmlReader` does not care either way, as long as you feed bytes into it. The `FileStream` can handle any file size, so just use that.

Comment: As for the "variable not defined" error - you must be using some kind of strict mode? Because I've recently answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58698280/) and there is no such error. But technically (e.g. in C#) you'd have to declare a variable before the `try` block in order to have it available in the `catch` block. OTOH, PowerShell by default lets you get away with undeclared variables. In C# you would use a `using` statement to handle disposable resources, PowerShell does not have `using`, which leaves you with `try/catch/finally` as next best thing.

Comment: The good thing about the `finally` block is, you can `return` a value in the `try` block and `finally` *still* would get executed. So get into the habit of putting your clean up code in `finally` blocks. Especially since `catch` is optional, doing `try/finally` is a reasonable construction.